# How to check if a string contains at least one word of another string?

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string:

```
str='General Merchandise Stores, Automotive Parts And Accessories Stores, Motor Vehicle Supplies And New Parts Wholesalers, Tire Dealers '
```

The goal is to test if the string in the array below is contained in `str`. I am running this code:

```
['general merchandise'].any? { |word| str.include?(word) } # => false
```

The string is there. Why is the result `false`?

Comment: Stick a `.downcase` in there if you want a case-insensitive match

Comment: Hi Michael - I forgot to mention, `str` is downcased.

Comment: @user984621 If that is the case, then it contradicts your question.

Comment: @user984621 `{ |word| str.downcase.include?(word) }` returns `true` for me.

Comment: `!!(str =~ /\bgeneral merchandise\b/i) #=> true` is perhaps easier.

Comment: I think the displeasure with the question is because the array on which `any?` is invoked contains a single string, so the expression is equivalent to `str.include?('general merchandise')`.

Comment: `str.downcase.include?('Auto') => true` illustrates another problem with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by downcasing str as Michael answered above:

str='General Merchandise Stores, Automotive Parts And Accessories Stores, Motor Vehicle Supplies And New Parts Wholesalers, Tire Dealers '

['general merchandise'].any? { |word| str.downcase.include?(word) } # => true